# Set Storage Engine for Table in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am currently trying to set the Storage Engine for a table, because from case to case MyISAM and InnoDB should be used. Unfortunately I did not find a way to set this in Hibernate, and I do not want to create each table by hand. My prefered way would be to anotate it in the Java-POJO, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

I've found [Hibernate: what's the difference between MySQLDialect and MySQLInnoDBDialect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368195/hibernate-whats-the-difference-between-mysqldialect-and-mysqlinnodbdialect), which tells me that setting the Dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect` would help (it says this for the InnoDB-Dialect, but it seems like one could choose the default dialect with this), but this method has two shortcommings: First, the dialect is chosen for all tables, and second, it creates a query like `CREATE TABLE xy(..) type=MyISAM` but the query would be correct with `engine=MyISAM`.

Also [Hibernate mysql innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103506/hibernate-mysql-innodb) says that there are defaults, and that I can overwrite them when creating tables, but not how - does somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect` or `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`, you should use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5MyISAMDialect` or `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`.

This way, it creates the table using engine=MyISAM or engine=InnoDB.

But this configuration is global and if you really have a reason to configure it for a single table, you could try:

- Hibernate import SQL (hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files). Add the path to a SQL file which contains the alter table into it.